# Cómo recorrer las subcarpetas para transferir propiedad de carpetas y ficheros de Google Drive a otro usuario

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive, g-suite

En mi script puedo transferir la propiedad de una carpeta/archivo de Google Drive (definiendo en una variable la ID), me gustaría poder recorrer las subcarpetas y que transfiriera la propiedad de ambos..

```
    //TRANSFERIR CARPETA
    function PropiedadCarpetas() 
    {
     var carpeta = DriveApp.getFolderById("AsDfGhJkL1234567zXcVbNmLKJ");
     //https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/AsDfGhJkL1234567zXcVbNmLKJ
     var archivos = carpeta.getFiles();
     var yo = "DUENO@DOMINIO.COM";
     var nuevoDueno = "NUEVODUENO@DOMINIO.COM"; 

     //carpeta.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
     carpeta.setOwner(nuevoDueno);
     //carpeta.removeEditor(yo);
     carpeta.addEditor(yo);

     while (archivos.hasNext())
     {
     var archivo = archivos.next();
     //archivo.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
     archivo.setOwner(nuevoDueno);
     //file.removeEditor(yo);
     archivo.addEditor(yo);
     }
    }
    --------------------------------------
    //TRANSFERIR ARCHIVO
    function TransferirArchivo(IDCarpeta, Dueno, NuevoDueno)
    {
     var Carpeta = DriveApp.getFolderById(IDCarpeta);
     var Archivos = Carpeta.getFiles();

     while (Archivos.hasNext())
     {
     var file = Archivos.next();
     file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
     file.addEditor(Dueno);
     file.setOwner(NuevoDueno);
     }
    }
```

No consigo encontrar la manera...

Comment: Esto sólo es posible si tienes una cuenta de Google Apps for Work: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/KiyOD7h57Zg;context-place=topicsearchin/drive/category$3Ameet-the-community%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false  Aunque, imagino que si transfieres la propiedad de una carpeta estás transfiriendo, en consecuencia, la propiedad de todo lo que contiene dicha carpeta. Al menos eso es lo lógico.

Comment: @A.Cedano: En Google Drive un elemento, ya sea carpeta o archivo puede tener como carpeta padre a ninguna, una o varias carpetas a la vez, por lo que "la lógica" no es la misma que la opera en otros administradores de archivos. Para muchos esto resulta confuso.

Comment: @Juan: Bienvenido. Te invito a que sigas el [tour] y leas [ask] para entender el funcionamiento básico de este sitio. En relación a tu pregunta,  considero que no es del todo clara, porque tu duda aparentemente es acerca de cómo recorrer el arbol de una carpeta a sus subcarpetas, sin embargo, en el título méncionas el cambio de propietario. Para efectos de claridad sería conveniente que hicieras mención de que estás usando una cuenta de G Suite. Por otro lado, el código debe ser [mcve], en específico, las líneas de código que has comentado, no deberían ir.

Comment: @Rubén Gracias. Aunque no me queda claro. Más bien, sigo siendo escéptico al respecto. ¿Alguna documentación?

Comment: @Rubén Con un enlace donde se explique eso me bastaría. Yo cuando hago una carpeta pública en Drive todos sus archivos vienen a ser públicos, así me lo advierte Google Drive cuando asigno permisos a las carpetas. No me parece para nada lógico tener en G Drive una carpeta en propiedad mientras que los archivos que hay dentro sean de otro usuario. Saludos.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56300/discussion-between-ruben-and-a-cedano).

Comment: @A.Cedano Si, es con cuentas Gapps for Work (lo he omitido por privacidad..)  Gracias!! y Juan Leeré todo que como bien dices soy nuevo y quizás no sean mis formas las adecuadas...  Gracias!!!!  y Ruben , veras, lo que pretendo es tanto carpetas y archivos pasen a ser propiedad de una cuenta G4work de 1TB (las normales tienen 30GB) para no saturar el espacio sabiendo que se comparte entre Gmail y GDrive. Seria a nivel empresarial, lo que hace que tener diferentes permisos en archivos y carpetas dependiendo de que nivel que la persona tenga en la organización, importante. Gracias igualmente!

Comment: No hay problema, era importante saber que se trataba de Google Apps (llamado ahora G-Suite) porque es la única posibilidad de transferir propiedad de archivos. Otra cosa, sólo permite transferir archivos creados dentro de Drive. No sé si has leído esto: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494892

Comment: La aseveración de que la única forma de transferir la propiedad de archivos es mediante cuentas de G Suite es incorrecta. También es posible hacer la transferencia usando cuentas de consumidor (por ejemplo con dominio gmail.com). Véase http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59143/es-posible-transferir-la-propiedad-de-los-archivos-de-google-drive-a-otra-cuent

Comment: He probado el código indicado en mi respuesta y funciona. Transfiere los archivos de una carpeta de un usuario a otro. Saludos.

Comment: Este código lo he probado en mi problemática actual aunque he desarrollado otro que de igual forma funciona parcialmente..
¿Por qué parcialmente? Pues simple, solo podéis cambiar la propiedad a otras personas del mismo dominio de los ficheros que seas propietarios, de los que no.. pues GAS no lo permite..
He estado usando cuentas de delegación de propiedad de todo el dominio a través de la API de Google Drive y pasa exactamente lo mismo..

Answer (score 3):

En el [servicio Drive](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/) de [Google Apps Script](https://www.google.com/script/start), las carpetas corresponden a una clase diferente a los archivos, [Class Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder), la cual, además del método getFiles cuentan con el método [getFolders](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfolders) para obtener las subcarpetas, y [getParentFolders](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getparents) para obtener las carpetas padre o superiores.

Estos métodos devuelven un objeto [Class FolderIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator), el cual es una colección que es potencialmente grande y que se puede recorrer usando el método [next()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator#next())

Ejemplo de la documentación de FolderInterator

```
// Log the name of every folder in the user's Drive.
var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
while (folders.hasNext()) {
  var folder = folders.next();
  Logger.log(folder.getName());
}
```

**Relacionado**

- [¿Es posible transferir la propiedad de los archivos de Google Drive a otra cuenta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59143/es-posible-transferir-la-propiedad-de-los-archivos-de-google-drive-a-otra-cuent)

Answer (score 1):

## ACTUALIZACIÓN

> He probado el siguiente código y funciona:

El código transfiere al nuevo usuario el folder indicado en el id y todos los archivos dentro de él. Al ejecutarlo por primera vez se pedirá autorización para acceder a Google Drive.

```
function folderTransfer()
{
  var fol = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID-DEL-FOLDER");
  var files = fol.getFiles();
  var me = "email@propietario.com";
  var newOwner = "email@destino.com";

  //Se pueden establecer otras opciones de compartir para el folder
  fol.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  fol.setOwner(newOwner);

  //Si se quiere quitar los derechos de edición del folder al actual propietario
  fol.removeEditor(me);

  while (files.hasNext())
  {
    var file = files.next();

    //Se pueden establecer otras opciones de compartir para el los archivos
    file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
    file.setOwner(newOwner);

    //Si se quiere quitar los derechos de edición de cada archivo del folder al actual propietario
    file.removeEditor(me);
  }
}
```

Luego de la transferencia el destinatario será notificado por correo electrónico y podrá encontrar la carpeta y/o archivos en su Google Drive. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Nota: En mi caso, cuando iba a verificar si la transferencia de dueño se había hecho correctamente, hasta pasados unos minutos o segundos, salía como propietario el usuario anterior. Pero luego de ese pequeño lapso de tiempo, todo normal.

---

### Documentación de Google sobre la transferencia de archivos y carpetas

#### Asignar la propiedad de un archivo a otra persona

De forma predeterminada, eres el propietario de los archivos que creas en Google Drive o que subes a dicho servicio. Puedes transferir la propiedad de tus archivos y carpetas de Google a otra persona que disponga de una cuenta de Google.

Antes de transferir la propiedad

Solo puedes transferir la propiedad de los archivos y las carpetas de Google. Si conviertes a otra persona en propietaria de una carpeta, seguirás siendo el propietario de los archivos que esta contenga. Más información sobre cómo compartir carpetas

**Archivos que puedes transferir**

- Documentos de Google
- Hojas de cálculo de Google
- Presentaciones de Google
- Formularios de Google
- Dibujos de Google
- Google My Maps
- Carpetas

Después de asignar la propiedad de un archivo a otra persona
Cuando conviertas a otra persona en propietaria de un archivo, no podrás:

- Transferir la propiedad del archivo (ni siquiera volver a asignártela a ti).
- Eliminar el archivo definitivamente de Google Drive.

Fuente: [Ayuda de Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494892)

Comment: El código no va a cambiar el propietario de los archivos en la carpeta inicial ya que el cambio se realiza en la función que es llamada dentro del while cuando existe una subcarpeta. Me llama atención que la publicación citada no cuenta con votos, ni positivos ni negativos y tampoco cuenta con comentario alguno y se menciona que no lo has probado ¿Qué fue lo que te animó a considerar dicha fuente?

Comment: @Ruben Aunque no tenga comentarios el código parece correcto. Queda a opción del OP probar si funciona, por eso lo he ofrecido como una posible solución. No puedo probarlo porque no tengo cuenta de G-Suite. P.D.: No habría votado en contra sin verificar que no funciona. ¿Quizá no te tomaste el tiempo de analizar el contenido del código? Se cambia la propiedad de todos los archivos en general o de todos los archivos de un folder determinado. Espero la apreciación del OP.

Comment: No hace falta cuenta de G-Suite para probarlo. Cabe destacar que en el código incluido, se incluyen cuentas de gmail.com.

Comment: @Rubén Agradezco tu indicación. **He probado el código y funciona**, con alguna modificación. Saludos.

Comment: He probado el script y funciona a la perfección, cambia la propiedad de una carpeta y de los documentos que contiene (sean o no documentos de Drive).
Mi pregunta es si sería posible ampliar el script para incluir subcarpetas y los documentos que contengan. Gracias por vuestra colaboración.

Comment: @Santi, sería mejor que plantees una nueva pregunta con tu duda, así podrás obtener varias respuestas de diferentes expertos, discutir algunos aspectos en los comentarios a las respuestas dadas si fuere necesario y quedarte con la mejor respuesta. No es conveniente abordar aquí otro aspecto, aunque parecido, diferente. No es acorde con el formato de Stackoverflow.