# ¿Es posible transferir la propiedad de los archivos de Google Drive a otra cuenta?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive

Me han dicho que Google Drive funciona diferente a los administradores de archivos comunes y que no es posible cambiar el propietario ni mediante la interfaz de usuario, ni usando el servicio Drive Google Apps Script ni la API de Google Drive

¿Es esto correcto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

Así es, en Google Drive la administración de los permisos de los archivos y carpetas de Google Drive funciona diferente a cómo lo hacen otros administradores de archivos.

## Explicación

### Limitaciones

1. Sólo se puede transferir la propiedad de archivos y carpetas entre cuentas del mismo dominio, de midominio.com a midominio.com o de gmail.com a gmail.com sí se puede, pero no se puede de midominio.com a gmail.com ni viceversa.
2. Sólo se puede transferir la propiedad de archivos en los formatos de Google, no se puede transferir la propiedad de "archivos subidos" tales como imágenes, videos, PDFs, etc.

Cabe mencionar que los archivos y carpetas en Google Drive podrían

1. tener ninguna, una o varias carpetas padre

   - Sí, aunque no lo creas, en Google Drive, es posible que un archivo o carpeta quede sin carpeta / unidad padre. Si no logras encontrar un archivo, consulta primero [Encontrar o recuperar un archivo](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/1716222?hl=es).
2. tener elementos con configuraciones diferentes de compartir, por lo que los cambios realizados en la carpeta padre podrían no ser desplegados a las archivos y carpetas hijos

En el caso de las cuentas de G Suite el administrador puede transferir los archivos de una cuenta a otra.

## Soluciones alternativas / workarounds

### Archivos "subidos"/sincronizados

Si bien usando cuentas de consumidor, como las que tienen dominio gmail.com, no es posible transferir los archivos subidos/sincronizados, si es posible copiarlos.

### Archivos y carpetas inter-dominios

En el caso de los archivos en formato de Google y de las carpetas inter-dominios, "podría" ser posible copiar los archivos. El "podría" en lugar de "puede" es que el propietario pudo haber configurado uno o varios de sus archivos para prevenir el que fueran copiados.

## Referencias

### Oficiales

#### Ayuda de usuario final

- [Transferir la propiedad de un archivo](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494892?hl=es),
- [Dejar de compartir o limitar o cambiar la configuración para compartir](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494893?hl=es)

#### Ayuda de administrador de G Suite

- [Transferir archivos de Drive a un nuevo propietario](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1247799/?hl=es)

### Auto-referencias

- [Rescatar Archivos y Carpetas Huérfanos de Google Drive](https://sites.google.com/site/ejemplosparaforos/blog/rescatararchivosycarpetashuerfanosdegoogledrive)

## Hilos relacionados

- [Cómo recorrer las subcarpetas para transferir propiedad de carpetas y ficheros de Google Drive a otro usuario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59102/transferir-propiedad-de-carpetas-y-ficheros-de-google-drive-a-otro-usuario) . Este hilo en realidad pregunta cómo recorrer las supcarpetas.

Comment: Por hacer: Revisar el uso de Google Team Drive como alternativa.