# Capturar datos correo Gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Estoy iniciándome con GAS, y estoy intentando crear un script que capture los datos de un correo enviado desde Gmail.

No encuentro ninguna propiedad de GmailApps que recoja está información, y los métodos que implementa no veo que ninguno haga referencia a ello.

La idea es capturar estos datos, y escribirlos en diferentes celdas de una hoja de cálculo.

¿Alguna idea al respecto?

Answer (score 0):

Parece que por el momento Google Script no permite acceder directamente a los mensajes enviados usando un método específico. Al menos no consta en la doc oficial.

No obstante, puedes valerte del método `search` de GmailApp, evaluando la condición `is:sent` y buscando en el thread `0` (la raíz de los mensajes enviados).

En este ejemplo, se indica que busque los primeros `5` mensajes de la carpeta `enviados` y se mostrará el asunto `getFirstMessageSubject` iterando sobre el arreglo `enviados`. Puedes usar [cualquier otro método](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread) para obtener los datos que te interesen.

De esta forma accedes a los mensajes enviados sin tener que pasar por métodos complicados tales como conocer el id del mensaje, etc.

Puedes aplicar una serie de filtros interesantes combinándolos con el método `search`. Podrás filtrar los mensajes por carpetas, por etiquetas, por destinatarios, por rangos de fecha... [**En este enlace podrás ver algunos ejemplos**](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190) que podrían ser útiles a la hora de filtrar los mensajes que quieres obtener.

```
var enviados = GmailApp.search("is:sent", 0, 5);
for (var i = 0; i < enviados.lenght; i++) 
{
     Logger.log (enviados[i].getFirstMessageSubject());
}
```

**Resultado de ejemplo**

Podrás ver un resultado parecido a este si pulsas en el menú `Ver - > Registros` de Google Script.

```
[17-04-12 19:36:54:792 CEST] Liturgia de la Semana Santa: Celebraciones del 10 al 16 de Abril, Pascua de la Resurrección de Nuestro Señor Jesucristo y Domingo 23 de Abril
[17-04-12 19:36:54:842 CEST] Domingo de Ramos
[17-04-12 19:36:54:899 CEST] PASAJE AVE
[17-04-12 19:36:54:955 CEST] Liturgia de la Semana V del Tiempo de Cuaresma: Celebraciones del 3 al 9 de Abril y el Domingo 16 de Abril
[17-04-12 19:36:55:022 CEST] Liturgia de la Semana IV del Tiempo de Cuaresma: Celebraciones del 27 de Marzo al 2 de Abril y el Domingo 9 de Abril
```

Comment: [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/) y la [API de Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/?hl=es-419) son dos cosas distintas. En el caso de GmailApp existe [getMessageById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getMessageById(String)) por lo que si es posible acceder a los mensaje enviados de forma directa.

Comment: @Rubén Ni el OP ni yo lo hemos encontrado. Si dices que es posible, muestra un ejemplo funcional. Lo del -1 no lo entiendo, ni tampoco en otra respuesta donde ofrecí un ejemplo funcionando. ¿Podrías explicar a qué se debe tu -1?  Gracias.

Comment: _¿mejor pregunta?_   Creo que la pregunta **está bastante clara**, en cambio tu intención es muy confusa y tu actitud también, como en esta respuesta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59175/29967 de la cual no te has retractado. Puedes publicar en ejemplo funcional que acceda a los mensajes enviados de Gmail usando Google Script, eso es lo que pide el OP. En cuanto al método que dices, no puedes acceder de forma directa, pues **debes conocer el id del mensaje** Saludos.

Comment: @Rubén _Favor de incluir la referencia o fundamento sobre el mismo._ Ya la tienes, pues posees ante tus ojos, **un código que funciona**. Mientras sigues pidiendo referencias, sigo esperando de tu parte alguna solución mejor, pero no veo ninguna. ¿Acaso eres el cacique de Google en esSO? Al menos te comportas como tal. ¡Qué fatiga! ¿Has probado mi solución? ¿Funciona o no funciona? Entonces... ¿cuál es tu problema?