# ¿Cómo puedo obtener manualmente el id de un mensaje de Gmail?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, gmail

He identificado un mensaje de Gmail del cual deseo extraer algunos datos. Para fines de esta pregunta digamos que se trata del asunto y que el ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable es el siguiente:

```
function myFunction() {
  var id = id_mensaje;
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(id);
  range.setValue( message.getSubject());
}
```

En Inbox by Gmail abrí el mensaje original y probé cambiando `id_mensaje` por

1. el id del URL

   `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0?ik=9b5582cf2d&view=om&permmsgid=msg-f:1564498808323854177`

Asumí que parámetro es permmsgid y que por ende el id sería

> msg-f:1564498808323854177

2. el valor del campo ID del mensaje

> <597438654.-1041137938.1492022331088.JavaMail.root@sjmas02.marketo.org>

Pero en ambos casos me muestra el error:

> Argumento no válido: (línea 3, archivo "Código")Ignorar

¿Cómo puedo obtener el id del mensaje usando la interfaz de usuario de Inbox by Gmail?

Comment: Es una pregunta _ficticia_ tomada de un problema real planteado aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/62479/capturar-datos-correo-gmail/62539 ... sólo que la pregunta **real** fue marcada para cierre. No estoy de acuerdo con que se actúe de esta manera en esSO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si bien Inbox by Gmail permite acceder a los mensajes de Gmail, la forma en que trabajan es muy diferente y algunos datos como los ids de los mensajes podría parecer más sencillos de obtener usando la interfaz de usuario de Gmail.

## Usando Inbox by Gmail o Gmail

1. Abrir el hilo del mensaje en cuestión
2. Hacer clic en el botón desplegable del mensaje (Gmail) o en el botón de los tres puntos (Inbox by Gmail), y luego seleccionar **Mostrar el original**
3. Se mostrará la página con los datos del mensaje orignal
4. Hacer clic con el botón derecho en **Descargar el mensaje original** y luego en **Copiar el URL**. En el clipboard, se incluirá un URL como el siguiente:

   `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0?view=att&th=15b6376089aa4f61&attid=0&disp=comp&safe=1&zw`

   El id del mensaje corresponde al parámetro `th` que en este caso es `15b6376089aa4f61`.

## Otra forma usando Gmail

En el caso del id del mensaje una forma de obtenerlo manualmente es siguiendo el siguiente procedimiento

1. Abrir el hilo del mensaje en cuestión en Gmail
2. Hacer clic en el botón desplegable del mensaje, y luego seleccionar **Imprimir**
3. Se mostrará la página de opciones de impresión con un URL como el siguiente

   `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=9b5582cf2d&view=pt&search=inbox&msg=15b6376089aa4f61&siml=15b6376089aa4f61`

   El id del mensaje corresponde al parámetro `msg` que en el caso del ejemplo es `15b6376089aa4f61`.